# ActionView error when deploying to Heroku, works fine locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, error-handling

I'm building a small app that uses the blazer gem - everything works fine until I try to create new query via "blazer/queries/new" and it gives me the following error. I can't seem to figure out the difference between production and local (works fine) that causes this error. I've eliminated ruby version, routing order, and asset recompilation, but have no idea what's going on. Thanks!

```
2016-09-17T22:32:35.124881+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010638+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/blazer/queries/new" host=... request_id=abfff554-2cdd-4c1d-b45a-24f0f4c76e1e fwd="94.97.85.176" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=1754
2016-09-17T22:33:14.003151+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/blazer/queries/new" for 94.97.85.176 at 2016-09-17 22:33:14 +0000
2016-09-17T22:33:14.005458+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Blazer::QueriesController#new as HTML
2016-09-17T22:33:14.007870+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/app/views/blazer/queries/_form.html.erb (1.2ms)
2016-09-17T22:33:14.007976+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/app/views/blazer/queries/new.html.erb within layouts/blazer/application (1.5ms)
2016-09-17T22:33:14.008106+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010487+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010489+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Empty url):
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010490+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:         <div class="pull-left" style="margin-top: 6px;">
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010491+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:           <%= link_to "Back", :back %>
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010491+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:         </div>
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010502+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:         <%= f.select :data_source, Blazer.data_sources.values.map { |ds| [ds.name, ds.id] }, {}, class: ("hide" if Blazer.data_sources.size == 1), style: "width: 140px;" %>
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010504+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:         <div id="tables" style="display: inline-block; width: 250px; margin-right: 10px;" class="hide">
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010504+00:00 app[web.1]:     20:           <%= render partial: "tables" %>
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010505+00:00 app[web.1]:     21:         </div>
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010506+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer/data_source.rb:16:in `initialize'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010507+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer.rb:73:in `new'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010508+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer.rb:73:in `block in data_sources'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010508+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer.rb:72:in `each'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010509+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer.rb:72:in `map'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010510+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/lib/blazer.rb:72:in `data_sources'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010512+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/app/views/blazer/queries/_form.html.erb:18:in `block in _vendor_bundle_ruby_______gems_blazer_______app_views_blazer_queries__form_html_erb___722781642157270755_69853702949320'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010522+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:202:in `with_output_buffer'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010522+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010523+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:444:in `form_for'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010524+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/app/views/blazer/queries/_form.html.erb:5:in `_vendor_bundle_ruby_______gems_blazer_______app_views_blazer_queries__form_html_erb___722781642157270755_69853702949320'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010525+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010525+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010526+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010527+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010527+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:339:in `render_partial'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010528+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310:in `block in render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010529+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010529+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:309:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010533+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010534+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010535+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/blazer-1.7.0/app/views/blazer/queries/new.html.erb:2:in `_vendor_bundle_ruby_______gems_blazer_______app_views_blazer_queries_new_html_erb__4212589811334821380_69853701401580'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010536+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010536+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010537+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010541+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010542+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010543+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010543+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010544+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010545+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010545+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010546+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010548+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010549+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010549+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010550+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010550+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010551+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010551+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010552+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010554+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010555+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010556+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010557+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010557+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010558+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010559+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010559+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010560+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010561+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010561+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010562+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010563+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010563+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010564+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010567+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010567+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010569+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010569+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010570+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010571+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010572+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010572+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010573+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010573+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010575+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010576+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010576+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010577+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010578+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010578+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010579+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010580+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010580+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010581+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010582+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010582+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010583+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010584+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010585+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010585+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010586+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010588+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010589+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010591+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010591+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010592+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010596+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010597+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010597+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010598+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010599+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010599+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010600+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010601+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010601+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010602+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010602+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010612+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010613+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010614+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010616+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010617+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010617+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010618+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010619+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010619+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010620+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010620+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010621+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010622+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-09-17T22:33:14.010622+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
```

Comment: The error is coming from `Blazer.data_sources`, right? Any Blazer configuration differences between dev and production?

Comment: Nothing that I can see - which files are there that determine differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - basically I needed to set my Blazer Environment variable within Heroku so I did this in the terminal:

```
heroku run rails c
> ENV['DATABASE_URL']
> *My Database URL*

heroku config:set BLAZER_DATABASE_URL=*My Database URL*
```

And it worked!